# How to handle user with no password in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I installed postgresql but it's asking me for passwords that I never had and never entered. There is a postgres ubuntu user and a database user named moodle. Neither of these were created with a password. Now that my system is asking me for those passwords, what should I do? Why is this process not easy?

```
$ psql -Umoodle -hlocalhost moodle < /var/www/vcmoodle/moodle/kth-install/moodle_fresh_postgres.sql 
Password for user moodle: 
psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
postgres@dac-VPCSA2Z9E:~$ sudo psql -Umoodle -hlocalhost moodle < /var/www/vcmoodle/moodle/kth-install/moodle_fresh_postgres.sql 
[sudo] password for postgres: 
postgres@dac-VPCSA2Z9E:~$ sudo -u moodle psql moodle
sudo: unknown user: moodle
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
postgres@dac-VPCSA2Z9E:~$ sudo -u postgres psql moodle
postgres is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
postgres@dac-VPCSA2Z9E:~$ sudo -u dac psql moodle
[sudo] password for postgres: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for postgres: 
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
postgres@dac-VPCSA2Z9E:~$ sudo -u postgres psql
postgres is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
postgres@dac-VPCSA2Z9E:~$
```

Comment: Security is intended to keep anyone from too easily doing things that they should not. Places to look:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres abd https://moodle.org/login/forgot_password.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `pg_hba.conf`, you should set:

`# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD`

```
local     all           all                                   trust
```

Authentication method should be `TRUST`, that will allow you to enter postgres without a password and set it for `postgres` user. Below you see how to change password using SQL:

```
ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'pass';
```

However, you should use `psql`'s `\password` instead, so the password change (and the password itself) is not logged under any circumstance.

From the [PostgreSQL 9.4.12 Documentation for `psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html):

> `\password [ username ]`
>
> Changes the password of the specified user (by default, the current user). This command prompts for the new password, encrypts it, and sends it to the server as an `ALTER ROLE` command. This makes sure that the new password does not appear in cleartext in the command history, the server log, or elsewhere.

Of course you should change option `TRUST` to for example `md5` later for security reasons.

Comment: Don't forget the semicolon at the end of the ALTER!